Exporting Dynamically Generated Div Data to Excel Using Kendo UI
I'm currently working on a project that involves exporting dynamically generated data from a div implemented in cshtml to an Excel file using Kendo UI. The content of the div is generated dynamically based on user interactions or server-side updates.
Due to the dynamic nature of the cshtml-generated content, I'm encountering challenges in accurately exporting this data to Excel. If anyone has experience with exporting dynamically generated div content to Excel using Kendo UI, I would greatly appreciate any insights or advice you could share.
I'm particularly interested in approaches or techniques that can handle dynamically changing data structures and ensure that the exported Excel file remains consistent and accurate.
This is how my UI looks which is exactly i need it exported to excel using Kendo 
Any input is appreciated
